# How to create a dynamic url c#

Tags: c#

This:

```
string sFile = @"E:\Proyect\Beta\websiges\files\temp\" + nameDoc() + tipeDoc;
```

This url reads an image , but do not want to have the url with the "E " direction as it is a web project and urls must be dynamic .
I tried to put it this way :

```
string sFile = @"~\files\temp\" + nameDoc() + tipeDoc;
```

But do not read the file.
I await your contribution , thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to resolve the `~` properly. You should be using [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of string concatenation, to reduce the risk of path injection.

```
string sFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~\files\temp\"), nameDoc(), tipeDoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string fileName = nameDoc() + tipeDoc;   
Path.Combine( path, fileName );
```